# Postman getting blocked by Spring Boot CSRF protection

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, csrf

I have a Spring Boot application that uses cookies for CSRF protection. I know that it works, but in Postman I can't get PUT, POST or DELETE to work. I am using Interceptor.

The cookies that I expect are being sent though: `XSRF-TOKEN=becb9b23-3fe5-4ff9-ba4c-338baea968c3;`, which is the same as the response XSRF-Token value: `becb9b23-3fe5-4ff9-ba4c-338baea968c3` so I don't know why the request is being blocked.

I know that the issue is CSRF, because if I disable it Postman works as expected.

I also know that CSRF works because I've built tests for it:

```
  @WithMockUser(authorities = TEST_AUTHORITY_ACCESS)
  @Test
  public void testPostSomething() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(post("/something").content(TEST_BODY).with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }

  @WithMockUser(authorities = TEST_AUTHORITY_ACCESS)
  @Test
  public void testPostSomethingWithoutCsrf() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(post("/something").content(TEST_BODY))
        .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
  }
```

So basically, if the correct cookie is being sent, and CSRF protection is working as expected, why is my request being blocked anyway?

Security Configuration (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/login").csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
        // ...
  }
```

The error message I receive in Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-24T11:19:00.324+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/something"
}
```